# Magento: Previewing template / theme?

Tags: magento, templates, themes, preview

I'm a web designer creating a new theme for a client's existing site, I don't have full access to the server so I'm not able to create a staging site for the purpose of testing a theme...

Is there a simple way to preview a custom theme without interfering with the live site in Magento 1.4 similar to Magento Go theme preview? Or if anybody has any other suggestions that would be great.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a test site on your own PC or Mac with Apache Friends Xampp, Download and install Magento. http://www.magentocommerce.com/download instruction here.

Now you can play and experiment without taking down a live site.
Be sure to read up on theme building.

Comment: As a designer databases make me run and hide, had to do a little trial and error to get the database to connect but with Xampp and Bitnami Stacks I've got it set up. Thanks for the tip!!